# Array Multidimensional PHP

Tags: php, html

Bem eu criei laços for para fazer os `inputs` da `matriz` em `html` com o seguinte código.

```
for($I=0; $I<5;++$I){
   for($J=0;$J<3;++$J){
      print" Matriz A: <input class='_InpText2' type='text' name='Matriz".[$I][$J]."' />";
   }
}

for($I=0; $I<5;++$I){
   for($J=0;$J<3;++$J){
       echo " Matriz B: <input class='_InpText2' type='text' name='Matriz".[$I][$J]."' />";
   }
}
```

Este código acima no ***Windows*** reproduz o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\php\exercises-chapter03\exercise06.php on line 30

a extensão do arquivo é `.php` e no ***Ubuntu*** não exibe este erro alguém sabe porque?

Comment: É porque deves ter os erros "escondidos", experimenta adicionar estas duas linhas: `error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` nas primeiras linhas do ficheiro

Comment: Mas o erro acontece porque estás a tratar as tuas variáveis como array, coloca somente: `'....Matriz".$I.$J."'...`

Comment: Como está a estrutura desse `print`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro é devido ao uso dos colchetes, e a concatenação. Tente a seguinte forma:

```
 <?php

for($I=0; $I<5;++$I){
   for($J=0;$J<3;++$J){
      print" Matriz A: <input class='_InpText2' type='text' name='Matriz".$I.$J."' />";
   }
}

for($I=0; $I<5;++$I){
   for($J=0;$J<3;++$J){
       echo " Matriz B: <input class='_InpText2' type='text' name='Matriz".$I.$J."' />";
   }
}


?>
```

Comment: Man era esse o problema mesmo, por essa linha de raciocínio ja até arrumei o laço que estava pegando os dados com $_GET[]. Obrigado pela ajuda.